# Unable to install R package gisfin in Github

Tags: r, github

I'm not understanding why I'm unable to install the `R` package `gisfin` in github...

```
library("devtools")
install_github("ropengov/gisfin")

Downloading GitHub repo ropengov/gisfin@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/ropengov/gisfin/zipball/master
Installing gisfin
Downloading GitHub repo hadley/ggplot2@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/hadley/ggplot2/zipball/master
Installing ggplot2
Downloading GitHub repo hadley/scales@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/hadley/scales/zipball/master
Error: Could not find build tools necessary to build scales
```

Here is my Session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.1.0   tidyr_0.6.0     dplyr_0.5.0     devtools_1.12.0 sp_1.2-3       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.7      rstudioapi_0.6   magrittr_1.5     lattice_0.20-34  R6_2.2.0         httr_1.2.1       pxweb_0.6.3      plyr_1.8.4      
 [9] tools_3.3.1      grid_3.3.1       data.table_1.9.6 DBI_0.5-1        git2r_0.15.0     withr_1.0.2      htmltools_0.3.5  lazyeval_0.2.0  
[17] assertthat_0.1   digest_0.6.10    tibble_1.2       RJSONIO_1.3-0    curl_2.1         memoise_1.0.0    evaluate_0.10    rmarkdown_1.1   
[25] stringi_1.1.2    chron_2.3-47
```

As per @R.S. comment:

```
devtools::has_devel()
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD SHLIB foo.c 

c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c foo.c -o foo.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o foo.dll tmp.def foo.o -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/x64 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Posting the output of  `devtools::has_devel()` might shed more light on the problem. It  *Checks if you have a development environment installed.*

Comment: Thanks @R.S. I've added that info into my question.

Comment: So gcc is present. check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914339/error-could-not-find-build-tools-necessary-to-build  It seems like user permission restriction causes this issue

Comment: @R.S. That's correct - I installed in base R (I was originally trying in R Studio) and it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: Great. I had recently grappled with similar situation on  Linux, though I was trying to uninstall a package. BTW, you mean you installed from the administrative  cmd prompt, right?

Comment: You might also be having problems because Github's DNS is under attack right now, so name resolution problems might be preventing you from downloading. [You might try manually add the IP to a hosts file.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40184256/4233593)