# How to install rword2vec package

Tags: r

Please provide me the steps how to install rword2vec. I referred to the previous posts and followed installation steps and got the error:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("mukul13/rword2vec")
Downloading GitHub repo mukul13/rword2vec@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/mukul13/rword2vec/zipball/master
Installation failed: Could not find build tools necessary to build rword2vec
```

I also tried to follow the steps regarding build tool provided in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35914339/3695939), but no success (I am using macOS).

Comment: Does `devtools::has_devel()` return `TRUE`? Is R installed as a user or as administrator? So by following [that answer's steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39682705/3358272), you say that you reinstalled R as the administrator and still have the problem? What versions of macOS and R are you running?

Comment: can you run `sessionInfo()` and share the output (by editing your question)?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Rtools (3.4 latest), mine showed similar error and automatically installed it. Hope it helps