# Unable to install Github packages in R

Tags: r, windows, github, installation

I need a packages witch is located on Github. And I am aware that there are multiple solutions to install the package in R.

I am trying to install the package on a Windows server. This is what I tried:

**Solution 1 (which is based on the Vignette)**

```
install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools") 
devtools::install_github("bmschmidt/wordVectors")

Error: Could not find tools necessary to compile a package
In addition: Warning messages: 
1: In strptime(xx, f, tz = tz): unable to identify current timezone 'C': 
Please set environment variable 'TZ'
```

**I tried many things to solve this:**

1. Reinstalling Devtools, use the CRAN devtools version
2. Reinstalling R and Rstudio (installing the latest versions as admin) ([Error : Could not find build tools necessary to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914339/error-could-not-find-build-tools-necessary-to-build))

But still the same error...

So I tried a workaround to install the packages on my computer:

**Solution two**

1. Download ZIP file from (https://github.com/bmschmidt/wordVectors)
2. Unzip the ZIP file

But the result is an error again:

```
 library(devtools) 
 install("path/to/unzipped/file") 
 library("wordVectors") 

Error there is no packages called wordVectors.
```

**Anyone an idea what is going on? I struggled the whole day with this issue.** Help is really appreciated! Thanks!

**Edit**
Also Rtools is (re)installed (the latest version...)

**Edit 2**
As requested in the comments (@DJV):

```
> sessionInfo()  
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.2 tools_3.5.2
```

Comment: Try installing [`Rtools`](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).From [this](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/issues/376#issuecomment-315757015) GitHub issue answer..

Comment: Thanks @patL, we already installed Rtools... unfortunately, without results..

Comment: I know it's a cliche but have you tried restarting your rstudio/machine (usually does the trick in windows)?. In addition, could you please add `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: I suspect R is not seeing your Rtools. When installing Rtools, make sure to check the box for "edit the system PATH". Then restart RStudio. Then load `library(devtools)` and see what `find_rtools()` returns. It should be TRUE.

Comment: Thanks @neilfws. Do you know where I can find the function? It is neither in the covr package. 

> library(devtools)
> find_rtools()
Error in find_rtools() : could not find function "find_rtools"

Comment: I'm following [this guide](http://stat545.com/packages01_system-prep.html). Perhaps it's outdated. Could try `pkgbuild::has_rtools()` and `pkgbuild::rtools_path()`.